# IE6 displaying components in a hidden div (when they should be hidden!)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, rendering

Does anyone know if IE6 ever misrenders pages with hidden `divs`? We currently have several `divs` which we display in the same space on the page, only showing one at a time and hiding all others.

The problem is that the hidden `divs` components (specifically option menus) sometimes show through. If the page is scrolled, removing the components from view, and then scrolled back down, the should-be-hidden components then disappear.

How do we fix this?

Answer (score 3):

One hack you could use is to move your div outside the screen:

```
MyDiv.style.left = "-1000px";
```

And then put it back on its original position when you want to show it.

Comment: Cheers for the idea. I can see why this should work, but for some reason it's not. Even trying style.left = "-10px"; didn't budge it.

Comment: I've used this technique myself and works great in IE 6.0, but I think your div needs to be absolutely positioned; it may not work otherwise.

Comment: Did as you suggested and changed the div (and its parent) to absolutely positioning. Works now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How are they hidden? using `display:none;` or `visibility:hidden;` ? are they absolutely positioned by any chance? IE6 has a z-Index problem and there are several hacks to deal with it.

Comment: They are hidden using "display:none;" - I'll try "visibility:hidden;" if it will help. They are absolutely positioned, any hacks to fix this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it contained in another absolutely or relatively positioned div?

Comment: You need to make sure both divs 'hasLayout' attribute is set. Read this article on this particular IE caveat - http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html